# timeout duration on linux

Tags: timeout, kill, command

I'm trying to run a command for 5 hours and 10 minuts.

I found out how to run it for 5 hours but I'm unable to run it for 5 hours and 10 minuts..

```
timeout -sKILL 5h mplayer -dumpstream http://82.201.100.23:80/slamfm -dumpfile slamfm.mp3
```

runs fine. But when I try

```
timeout -sKILL 5h10m mplayer -dumpstream http://82.201.100.23:80/slamfm -dumpfile slamfm.mp3
```

I get this error

> timeout: invalid time interval `5h10m'

Does anyone know a way to run this command for 5 hours and 10 minuts and then kill it?

Comment: timeout -sKILL "5h 10m" mplayer -dumpstream http://82.201.100.23:80/slamfm -dumpfile slamfm.mp3 doesn't work either..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always try doing 310 minutes instead.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Why didn't I think about that? Thanks man!

Comment: It's Monday, I think that gives you a free pass.